# Bootstrap 4 Collapse are opening all items together

Tags: php, database, bootstrap-4

I have a dynamic page where Bootstrap Collapse is showing data from the database. Here if I click any link all the items's collapse is opening all together and closing altogether. My Code

```
<?php             
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($notice)) {
?>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion6" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne6">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion6" href="#collapseOne6" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne6">
                    <?php echo $row['title']; ?>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne6" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne6">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <?php echo $row['description']; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

 <?PHP }?>
```

Comment: You're going to have multiple divs with the same ID. Change your code so that each div in the loop has a unique ID.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 4 Collapse are opening and closing all items together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58698346/bootstrap-4-collapse-are-opening-and-closing-all-items-together)

Answer (score 0):

Your id's need to be different for each dropdown.

```
<a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion6" href="#collapseOne6" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne6">
    <?php echo $row['title']; ?>
</a>
```

Above each id matches `#accordion6`. So any other dropdowns need to be unique. Example `#accordion7`, `#accordion8`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I see

```
id="headingOne6"
```

in while loop

they have the same id and target href

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code to generate unique ids for `headingOne`.

```
<?php

   $i=0;
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($notice)) {

?>

 <div class="panel-group" id="<?php echo 'accordion'.$i; ?>" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="<?php echo 'headingOne'.$i; ?>">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="<?php echo '#accordion'.$i; ?>" href="#<?php echo $i; ?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="<?php echo 'collapseOne'.$i; ?>">
                    <?php echo $row['title']; ?>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="<?php echo $i; ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="<?php echo 'headingOne'.$i; ?>">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <?php echo $row['description']; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<?PHP 
    $i++;
}?>
```