# Bootstrap 4 Collapse are opening and closing all items together

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a dynamic page where Bootstrap Collapse is showing data from the database. Here if I click any link all the items' collapse is opening all together and closing altogether. Then I tried to create a unique id using a while loop but after that collapse is not working.

```
<?php                    
   $i=0;
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($notice)) {                     
?>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion6" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne6">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion6" href="#<?php echo $i; ?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne6">
                    <?php echo $row['title']; ?>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="<?php echo $i; ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne6">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <?php echo $row['description']; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?PHP 
    $i++;
}?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 4 Collapse are opening all items together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58696135/bootstrap-4-collapse-are-opening-all-items-together)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is generating duplicating id `headingOne6`. I have modified your code to generate a unique id.

```
<?php

   $i=0;
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($notice)) {

?>

 <div class="panel-group" id="<?php echo 'accordion'.$i; ?>" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="<?php echo 'headingOne'.$i; ?>">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="<?php echo '#accordion'.$i; ?>" href="#<?php echo $i; ?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="<?php echo 'collapseOne'.$i; ?>">
                    <?php echo $row['title']; ?>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="<?php echo $i; ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="<?php echo 'headingOne'.$i; ?>">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <?php echo $row['description']; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<?PHP 
    $i++;
}?>
```